# analysing pandas groupby output

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following csv file

```
Hour, L,  Dr, Tag, Code,   Vge
 0,   L5, XI, PS,  4R,     15
 5,   L5, XI, PS,  4R,     12
 2,   L0, St, v2T, 4R,     11
 8,   L2, TI, sst, 4R,     8
 12,  L5, XI, PS,  4R,     18
```

I am using the following python code.The idea is to wrap my head around pandas groupby concept.

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import pprint

df = pd.read_csv('in.csv')
gb = df.groupby('Hour')
pprint.pprint(list(gb))
```

This is the output that I get.

```
 [(0,
      Hour      L    Dr  Tag  Code   Vge
0      0        L5   XI   PS    4R   15),
 (2,
     Hour       L    Dr   Tag  Code     Vge
2     2         L0   St   v2T    4R     11),
 (5,
     Hour       L    Dr  Tag  Code      Vge
1     5         L5   XI   PS    4R      12),
 (8,
     Hour       L    Dr   Tag  Code      Vge
3     8         L2   TI   sst    4R      8),
 (12,
     Hour       L    Dr   Tag  Code     Vge
4    12         L5   XI   PS    4R      18)]
```

The `groupby` seems to have inserted `0,1,2,3,4`. It would be great if someone can explain what is happening in the data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 0,1,2,3,4 is the Pandas dataframe internal index